# Trying to find leap years and non leap years in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, leap-year

I'm trying to find the leap years and non leap years within a number range. The leap year and non leap years need to be put into separate arrays and I will be outputting them into a table later. I'm pretty new to JavaScript and I suspect that my looping may be wrong, i'm not sure.

My problem is that the non-leap year array is not getting all the numbers it needs. I enter 1900 - 2000 and the leap years seem to be alright, but the non leap year array only went up to 1930. I've been trying to fix it for a while, but I've had no luck.

Edit: The `for` loops are there only for me to test the arrays.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <title>LeapYears</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */


            function calcLeapYear() {

                var beginYear = document.leapYears.firstYear.value;
                var endYear = document.leapYears.secondYear.value;
                var leapYrs = new Array();
                var nonLeapYrs = new Array();

                var ctr = 0
                var ctr2 = 0
                while (beginYear < endYear){

                    if (((beginYear % 4 == 0) && (beginYear % 100 != 0)) || (beginYear % 400 == 0)) { /* Determines if year is a leap year or not */
                        leapYrs[ctr] = beginYear;
                        ++ctr;
                    }
                    else {
                        nonLeapYrs[ctr2] = beginYear;
                        ++ctr2;
                    }

                    ++beginYear;
                }

                if (leapYrs == 0){
                        window.alert("There were no leap years within the range.");
                    }

                for (i=0;i<leapYrs.length;i++){    //Testing Calculation
                    document.write(leapYrs[i] + "<br/>");
                }

                document.write("<br/>")

                for (i=0;i<leapYrs.length;i++){
                    document.write(nonLeapYrs[i] + "<br/>");
                }

            }

        /* ]]> */
        </script>


    </head>


    <body>
        <form name="leapYears">

            Beginning Year: <input type="text" name="firstYear" /> End Year: <input type="text" name="secondYear" /> 
            <input type="button" value="Find Leap Years" onclick="calcLeapYear()" />

        </form>

    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: your `var` lines for `ctr` and `ctr2` are missing semicolons

Comment: also, you don't even need counters, you can just use `leapYrs.push(beginYear)` and similar to add an element to an array

Comment: I'll have to look into this push() method, Just started covering arrays recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop when you `document.write` the contents of `nonLeapYrs` is looping over only the length of `leapYrs` so it will only print part of the array.

Comment: I hate when I miss small things like this. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: If this fixes it, please hit the button to accept it as the answer :)